# How to access contents of NSDictionary from JSON data request

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to access the contents of a dictionary using the following code and can't get it to work for some reason.

the         `NSLog(@"self.userCommentsArray %@",self.userCommentsArray);` 
returns null

thanks for any help with this.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
NSDictionary *userCommentsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"userCommentsDictionary %@",userCommentsDictionary); // this works

    self.userCommentsArray = [[userCommentsDictionary objectForKey:@"from"] objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"self.userCommentsArray %@",self.userCommentsArray);
```

here's the nslog output for the dictionary:

```
userCommentsDictionary {
        data =     (
                    {
                created = "2013-07-16T18:42:56+02:00";
                from =             {
                    id = 27;
                    name = "user-4";
                };
                id = 2553;
                message = "liquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
            },
                    {
                created = "2013-07-16T18:42:56+02:00";
                from =             {
                    id = 28;
                    name = "user-5";
                };
                id = 2554;
                message = "x ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
            },
                    {
                created = "2013-07-19T16:18:56+02:00";
                from =             {
                    id = 24;
                    name = "user-1";
                };
                id = 5125;
                message = test comment;
            },
                    {
                created = "2013-07-19T17:00:21+02:00";
                from =             {
                    id = 24;
                    name = "user-1";
                };
                id = 5126;
                message = "test comment ";
       }
        );
        meta =     {
            totalCount = 18;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Just have a look at your dictionary. The top-level key is "data", and its value is an *array* ... . Perhaps you can figure it out from there.

Comment: Yep, peel the onion, one layer at a time.  Don't try to "short circuit" things with expressions like `[[userCommentsDictionary objectForKey:@"from"] objectForKey:@"name"]`, since it makes it impossible to debug the intermediate steps.  (That expression is returning nil, without a doubt.)

Comment: Hint: There is no key "from" in userCommentsDictionary.  The only two keys are "data" and "meta".

Comment: Note that, in an NSLog dump of Objective-C objects, `()` brackets an array while `{}` brackets a dictionary.  When you look at the source JSON, on the other hand, `[]` brackets an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `userCommentsDictionary` has one entry with a key of `data`. This value is an array.

You need something like this:

```
NSArray *data = userCommentsDictionary[@"data"];
NSDictionary *firstComment = data[0];
NSDictionary *from = firstComment[@"from"];
NSString *name = from[@"name};
self.userCommentsArray = name;
```

This assumes you want the data from the first comment. Adjust as needed.

Notice the user of lots of intermediate variables. This makes your code much easier to read and debug. Avoid lines like this:

```
self.userCommentsArray = userCommentsDictionary[@"data"][0][@"from"][@"name"];
```

This is very hard to debug.

Update: If you actually want an array of all names, then you can do this:

```
NSArray *data = userCommentsDictionary[@"data"];
NSArray *names = [data valueForKeyPath:@"from.name"];
self.userCommentsArray = names;
```

Comment: Typo NAArray :) And I learnt new thing `@"from.name"` great. Thanks & +1 for this.

Comment: I think you need `valueForKeyPath` in your last code example.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@"data"` key, Which is root of json response. I assume that you want to fetch all names, So you can do something like this.

```
NSArray *data = userCommentsDictionary[@"data"];
// data array is an array of dicionaries

NSArray *from = [data valueForKey:@"from"];
//from array will fetch all "from" dictionaries 

NSArray *names = [from valueForKey:@"name"];
// names array will contain all names
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to access an object from the array at some index and then you can pick out the name field from that. FOr example:

```
self.userCommentsArray =  [userCommentsDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
id someObject  = [self.userCommentArray objectAtIndex:0] // or some other index
NSString *name = [someObject valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: This won't work. The call to `[self.userCommentArray objectAtIndex:0]` will return an `NSDictionary`. There is no `name` property on a dictionary.

Comment: sorry.  use value for key:@"name"

Comment: Update your answer with the correction.

Comment: That still doesn't work. `someObject` is a dictionary with the keys `from`, `created`, `id`, and `message`.

Comment: You need to go down another level in the nesting and pick out the object for the @"from" key and then pick out the @"name"key from that.